# Updating WPF application

Tags: wpf, installshield

I don't know if its possible guys, really need some help!

I have a WPF application and I am creating msi file for this using InstallShield. I want my user to give this option: If they have previously installed some version then I need to give them the option of either updating the application(thus saving the data) or completely uninstall the previous version and then install the current one. I have read some articles, that I need to change the product version/product code/ upgrade code. But I couldn't figure out what I really have to do.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should be using [Click Once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Comment: I am still going through the link, but i need to distribute my application as an windows installer(.msi or setup.exe). Would it be possible to have this feature in windows installer?

Comment: See the [Updates to setup projects](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/) page on the Simple Talk website.